# Do I need to insulate down conductors in a lightning protection system?

Tags: surge-protection, lightning, iec

When we install seperate down conductors in an external lightning protection system, do we need to fully insulate it or need to insulate in touchable areas? Is there any requirements in IEC 62305 standard like that or generally are they insulate it?

Comment: Is this really the sort of thing you want to be attempting as a DIY project?  You really won't know if it's done properly until it matters a lot, and then you will not get a chance to correct any deficiencies.

Comment: @jwh20 What makes you think it's a DIY project? If they are asking about IEC requirements it's more likely that they are a professional.

Comment: @AndrewMorton They are asking about IEC 62305, there might be someone on the site that knows about it

Comment: @AndrewMorton My best friend's grandma was struck twice by lightning. Time got him before the third lightning strike did.

Comment: I am pretty sure I read about using metal handrails on exterior staircases as downconductors. On the Mike Holt website. So I don't think they need to be insulated. I mean, it is lighning. If you touch the outside of an insulated cable while it conducts lightning to ground you are going to be in for a wild ride anyway. I am not sure how much difference it makes whether it is insulated or not. But I am not in any way qualified to answer authoritatively.

Comment: Maybe this should be migrated to diy anyway, though. It is more like an electrical code question than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference standard is the IEC/EN 62305-3 (in *italic* quoted text).

A down conductors connects the air terminal to the earthing system, and usually goes down from  roof or so some meters before reaching it.

A down conductor can be a specific conductor (usually copper, min req for cross section approx 50 mm2; I say "approx"  because in case of ensured mechanical protection it may be 28 mm2, but in Middle East local regulations go for 70 anyway) or can be a natural down conductor, so exploiting the building steel reinforcement, metal framework, etc.

Since we have mentioned metal works it implies that a down conductor shall not be insulated always. There are cases of non insulated down conductors.

**When is it necessary to insulate it?**

In brief: when it is dangerous if touched and when the discharge would cause fire.

Made longer:

1. sec. 5.3.4 prescribes 10 cm from building wall, if this is made of readily combustible material (thanks!)
2. An isolated external LPS (Lightning Protection System) must be used; as per sec. 5.1.2 again in case of explosion, and ... for electromagnetic compatibility, when equipment to protect is potentially susceptible to the discharge along the LPS => almost always
3. specifically for touch voltages sec. 8 clarifies the following.

   The touch voltage hazard is reduced if:

- *a) under normal operation conditions there are no persons within 3 m from the down conductors;*
- *b) a system of at least 10 down-conductors complying with 5.3.5 is employed;*
- *c) the contact resistance of the surface layer of the soil, within 3 m of the down-conductor, is not less than 100 kohm.*

Otherwise:
=> isolate the down conductor:
*giving a 100 kV, 1,2/50 us impulse withstand voltage, e.g. at least 3 mm cross-linked polyethylene*

Answer (score -2):

As far as I am aware Lightning protection is regarded as earth (It should be connected to earth at multiple points). and so may be bare.  The main concern is to insulate it from any metal surfaces, including any potential re-bar, water pipes, electrical connections
Also the insulation must prevent any fire from a hit.

Comment: I didn't downvote and I don't know much about lightning protection but I suspect that the very large currents involved will result in substantial voltages along the conductor so while it it may be earthed it won't be at earth potential. Tip: since it's not a proper noun (brand name, etc.) "lightning" doesn't get a capital 'L'.

Comment: Downvoted because: 1) we are speaking of a Lightning Protection System that must guarantee equipotential bonding with exposed parts while it is said "insulate from any potential re-bar"; besides that is not clear (potential + re-bar) if it is an earth bar or  reinforcement rebar, it is required to be interconnected: the important point is where & how. 2) The question asked for insulation as for "touchable" and made explicit ref to the 62305 standards. Nevertheless "fire" is a good point.